# Field sets not displaying the default values for picklist

Tags: fieldsets

On case object we have created a field set. we have 3 record types for Case and for all the record types, we have set a default value for "Case Origin" field.

In a custom VF page, we have custom button to create a new case, on the page, we are displaying the fields from field sets; however, when the page loads, we want the case origin to default to a value which we have for all record types.

Is there a way to default a pick list value when using field sets.

```
SObjectType.Case.FieldSets.NewCaseAddtionalInfo.getFields();
```